# How do I modify contents of a directory without sudo?

Tags: sudo, chmod, chown

I'm trying to modify the contents of a directory using `git`. Problem is if I use `sudo` it nullifies my ssh forwardAgent. I'm not the owner of the directory but I am part of it's group. If I `chmod 775` shouldn't I be able to make changes to the directory without `sudo` since I'm part of the group that owns it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files and subdirectories of the directory also need to be group-owned by the group.

The directory's owner (or root) needs to:

```
chgrp -R groupname /path/to/directory
chmod -R ug+rwX /path/to/directory
find /path/to/directory -type d -exec chmod g+s {} +
```

Making the directories setgid (e.g. with the `find` command above) ensures that all new files created in the directory will be in the group.  `umask` still controls the default permissions of created files, so the `umask` of all users who create files in that dir needs to be at least `002` to get perms `664` for files and `775` for dirs.

Comment: Perfect... thanks @cas. What does the `{} +` do at the end of the last command?

Comment: The `{}` tells find where to insert the list of found dirs in the command that it is `-exec`-ing, i.e. the `chmod g+s` command.  The `+` tells `find` to insert as many dir names as it can fit onto the one `chmod` command line, rather than run one `chmod` command per dir.